# How to get location of variable name in clang::VarDecl

Tags: c++, clang

I'm using clang 3.0 library for some analysis of C/C++ code, and I need to get location of variable declaration, I tried this code:

```
clang::VarDecl * vd = ...;
clang::SourceManager & srcMgr = ...;

clang::SourceRange loc = vd->getSourceRange();
clang::PresumedLoc locStart = srcMgr.getPresumedLoc(loc.getBegin());
clang::PresumedLoc locEnd = srcMgr.getPresumedLoc(loc.getEnd());
```

But **locStart** and **locEnd** points to the beginning (and ending) of declaration variable (with type, and, possibly initialiser). For example:

```
const char * ptr = 0;
^            ^ ^   ^
```

**locStart** will point at the first  pointer(`^`) , and locEnd will point at the last pointer. How can I get the location of the second and third pointers (only name, without type and initialiser)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently not in the position to test it but I think you want to extract the `SourceLocation` obtained by `getLocation()` from your `VarDecl`. This function is actually defined by the `Decl` base class. Although it seems to identify just one location it seems to be usable to identify the entire name (I haven't tried to extract its individual ends, however, just used it to indicate the variable).

Comment: Sorry, but `getQualifierLoc()` does not helps. This function returns `NestedNameSpecifierLoc`, and for my case it returns empty object (without any information).

Comment: Yes, you are right: this is actually for the location of things like `const` or `volatile`. I have tested with a sample program and it seems that it is as simple as using `getLocation()`: while the `VarDecl` itself want to start with the type, the `SourceLocation` returned by `getLocation()` seems to identify the name.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps, i dont know, why i started to use `getSourceRange`, `getLocation` works for me!

Comment: @Alexey - Please post the code in answer to get better understanding and reference.